# git clone hangs forever on github

Tags: git, ssh, github

When I follow point 5 (Test everything out) in the github [guide](http://help.github.com/linux-set-up-git/), the ssh command also hangs forever. According to the guide, I should be presented with a message that "Github does not provide shell access". Below is my output from ssh -vT git@github.com

```
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to github.com ([207.97.227.239]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LC_MESSAGES = en_US.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_COLLATE = en_US.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LANG = da_DK.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_CTYPE = en_US.UTF-8
```

Comment: Is there potentially any sort of filtering/blocking between you and GitHub?

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you able to connect to other SSH servers (using keys) without issues?

Comment: I also thought it may be filtering but notice the auth succeeds, if it were a firewall it would timeout eventually before that.

Comment: I tried every workaround mentioned here & even double checked using the `ssh -T git@github.com` command which appears to be working fine. Yet the connection times out over port 22.

Answers from this thread - https://stackoverflow.com/q/15589682/8604951 might help someone connect to GitHub properly while this thread -- https://stackoverflow.com/q/25927914/8604951 should help set up access rights to the remote in GitHub properly.

But in the end, cloning over HTTPS worked for me. It's not worth the pain IMHO to set up a SSH connection unless TOTALLY necessary.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think I found the error. The WiMAX router I am using, messes SSH up. After trying another
internet connection, it went smooth. The WiMAX router is branded
"Alvarion", and according to a Danish Google Group the NAT
implementation is broken in the router:
http://groups.google.com/group/openspaceaarhus/browse_thread/thread/e99d96122a0522b7.

I have contacted the internet supplier to look into this. If they prove it has nothing to do with their router I will post it here.

Thank you all for your comments, which made me realise it maybe was an infrastructure problem.

Comment: You should accept this as the "correct answer" and upvote the other helpful ones.

Comment: The company (Skyline) using this router went out of business short after, so I never found a solution for this router.

Comment: Using a VPN fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 61):

In my case port 22 was being blocked by a firewall, cloning via `https` may not work if you have 2-factor authentication enabled. Instead edit your .ssh config to use another port. In your terminal:

```
nano ~/.ssh/config
```

then add this:

```
Host github.com
  Hostname ssh.github.com
  Port 443
```

Comment: Just save me several minutes of digging around to find a solution.  Thx!!!

Comment: Worked for me as well. All my ssh requests were hanging forever. Creating a ~/.ssh/config and adding some config there fixed my issue. Here's some [additional resource](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/troubleshooting-ssh/using-ssh-over-the-https-port) from GitHub

Comment: This worked. I did add an exception to ssh.exe firewall rules but no thanks to managed firewall it does not function like I wanted to. Updating a config file is an extra step. For windows users: default location for adding such config file, with name "config" C:\Users\<UserNameHere>\.ssh\config where no file type is set

Answer (score 58):

GitHub offers a few different ways to connect to the remote repo.  I am behind an onerous firewall.  All methods also hang **except** using http (*not* https).

For example, the JavaHamcrest project offers (anonymously):

- https://github.com/hamcrest/JavaHamcrest.git
- git@github.com:hamcrest/JavaHamcrest.git
- git://github.com/hamcrest/JavaHamcrest.git

You may also try:

- http://github.com/hamcrest/JavaHamcrest.git

Finally, prefix your UNIX command with `GIT_TRACE=1` and `GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1`, and use Git option `--verbose` for maximum debug output.

Example: `env GIT_TRACE=1 GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 git clone --verbose http://github.com/hamcrest/JavaHamcrest.git`

Comment: It appears `http` (not `https`) links doesn't work for `github` anymore. I.e. your example command doesn't work as it's using `http` scheme.

Comment: also check that you github account has ssh keys - https://inchoo.net/dev-talk/how-to-generate-ssh-keys-for-git-authorization/

Answer (score 30):

**Try using HTTPS instead of SSH**. Port 22 might be blocked by a firewall.

E.g. instead of:

```
git clone git@bitbucket.org:repo-owner/my-project.git
```

Connect via `HTTPS`:

```
git clone https://username@bitbucket.org/repo-owner/my-project.git
```

Comment: Works on my hosting. The weird thing is that the other method used to work fine before.

Comment: Some VCs are disabling HTTPS, although you can still use it for cloning and then change the remote to SSH

Comment: I got here having issues with Docker, using HTTPS instead of SSH fixed it for me.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that you have ssh installed.

Ubuntu: `sudo apt-get install ssh`

Comment: even your ssh installed, probably you need to upgrade them.

I found it works for me after i upgrade them.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue on Xubuntu. Doing `ssh -Tv git@github.com` hangs forever. Disabling the firewall with `sudo ufw disable` solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Was having the same issue on Windows / msys2.  Seems to be something with the router.  I pinged github.com and then cloned using my username

`git clone https://cchamberlain@github.com/cchamberlain/<repo>`

and it worked.  Not sure if its a one-off yet.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I found that my Anti-Virus was blocking access to Github. The popup  appeared behind all my windows which I did not realize earlier. The moment I allowed access to GitHub "ssh -vT git@github.com" command worked. I was also able to clone a repository and push my code from local to Github.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a different default SSH port in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, git clone won't work out of the box with a `git@...` url.

[This solution above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57789765/3827487) to the rescue.

Answer (score 0):

Things to check when git clone and git push hang forever no error message

- you already have SSH keys configured for you github account - also check that you github account has ssh keys - https://inchoo.net/dev-talk/how-to-generate-ssh-keys-for-git-authorization/
- your firewall/antivirus is not blocking your traffic

Answer (score 0):

In my case was IPV6 blocking cloning, I disable ipv6 on ssh and works

Answer (score 0):

Mine dumb case was that, I changed default SSH port in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` instead of `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

Answer (score 0):

Cloning it again solved the issue for me. Try again.

Answer (score 0):

In my case an authentication/authorization pop-up window presented but somehow ended up being hidden behind other windows so I didn't see it.  I minimized other windows to find it, logged in, and git clone continued normally.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the MacOS keychain contains credentials, initially given from VS Code for github.com for the VS Code sync feature. I dont know, what I've changed in the meantime, maybe switched to 2FA, but with this credentials I was unable to login to github.com from the command line, neither via ssh nor https. After I've deleted the github.com entry in MacOS keychain, it works.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in mtu, my problem was solved like this:

```
sudo ip link set mtu 100 dev eth0
```

And then git clone

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score -1):

I was just struggling with that (after updating to using API Token instead of password, changes on github since July'21)

What helped me was to use http instead of https in git clone.

Simple as that.

Answer (score -1):

in my case my `/etc/resolv.conf` was messed up, i noticed pc would fail to even `ping google.com`. Fixed that that and life was grand.