# How to fix "ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Connection timed out" for git push/pull/... commands?

Tags: git, ssh

I am under a proxy and I am pushing in to git successfully for quite a while.
Now I am not able to push into git all of a sudden.
I have set the RSA key and the proxy and double checked them, with no avail and git is throwing me the error shown in the title of the page.

Comment: Create a hotspot on your mobile device, connect via your mobile device, then `git push`. Worked for me.

Comment: For Jenkins, see: [Why is Jenkins failing when fetching from git?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24813816/55075)

Comment: The same problem happened to me in the UK with Virgin Media. I tried to push/pull to GitHub via ssh at home and no luck but at work was fine. So I realised that I got problems with my ISP. The simple fix for me was to use Cloudflare DNS `1.1.1.1` instead of a default one that's why @zundi succeed through a mobile hotspot.

Comment: This worked for me -> https://gist.github.com/Tamal/1cc77f88ef3e900aeae65f0e5e504794

Comment: Very weird! But I closed my Postman and it solved it!!!  (Win10)

Comment: @zundi I'm at an airbnb place and the host has done some funky things to his wifi. Thanks to you I was able to push.

Comment: @zundi weird, but worked! Thanks!

Comment: @VladyslavKrylasov I have had the exact same problem, also uk virgin media, and tried your approach. Worked perfectly! Thanks!

Answer (score 341, accepted):

The reason could be the firewall modification since you are on a network, in which case they may deliberately block some ports.

To double check if this is the reason, run:

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

This should timeout.  If that's the case, then use the `http` protocol instead of ssh.  Change your url in the config file to `http`:

```
git config --local -e
```

and change:

```
 url = git@github.com:username/repo.git
```

to

```
url = https://github.com/username/repo.git
```

Comment: I had that issue once, but restarting my computer solved it.

Comment: fatal: unable to access 'https://gitlab.com:******.git/': Port number ended with 'f'

Comment: I had to remove the .git from the url in order for this to work for me.

url = https://github.com/username/repo/

Comment: restarting my system did the job...sometimes your proxy gets updated once your systems restarts.

Comment: using https instead for ssh is not the right solution.
There must a way to set proxy in git config and in ssh settings to solve this.

Comment: @VihariPiratla ok this works but how can i solve the port 22 unreacheable , so i can keep using ssh key

Comment: This happens when I am in my university's network, it blocks some websites. Changing to http or changing the network solves the issue.

Comment: This disables using the ssh key, doesn't it?

Comment: Virgin Media UK has a child safe mode, which I had to disable.

Comment: As he suggested, I directly cloned my repo with git `https://github.com/USERNAME/REPO.git`!!

Comment: As @FinlayPercy mentioned, it was the Virgin Media wifi causing the issue. Used Personal Hotspot from Phone network and it worked. I was trying to push repo to github

Answer (score 796):

For me none of the suggested solutions worked so I tried to fix it myself and I resolved it. I was getting this error on my AWS EC2 UBUNTU instance. I edited the ssh config (or add it if it does not exist).

`nano ~/.ssh/config`

And I added the following

```
Host github.com
 Hostname ssh.github.com
 Port 443
```

Then, run the command `ssh -T git@github.com` to confirm if the issue is fixed.

According to [this](https://help.github.com/articles/using-ssh-over-the-https-port/)

> Sometimes, firewalls refuse to allow SSH connections entirely. If using HTTPS cloning with credential caching is not an option, you can attempt to clone using an SSH connection made over the HTTPS port. Most firewall rules should allow this, but proxy servers may interfere

Hopefully this helps anyone else who's having the same issue I did.

Comment: This solution worked fine for me, although it didn't solve the issue for GitLab.

In that case, please consider that GitLab.com runs a second SSH server that listens on the commonly used port 443, which is unlikely to be firewalled.

All you have to do is edit your `~/.ssh/config` and change the way you connect to GitLab.com.

In that case, see this article: https://about.gitlab.com/2016/02/18/gitlab-dot-com-now-supports-an-alternate-git-plus-ssh-port/

Comment: Hi, i had a same problem, my router is from NET and him block the 22 port. That config solved my problem definitely

Comment: It is not `git` config but `ssh` config

Comment: After hours of finding anwers... you're CHAMP, anyway why do we need to change github.com to ssh.github.com? I still don't get it

Comment: For create a ssh config file : https://linuxize.com/post/using-the-ssh-config-file/

Comment: This solution worked for me as I'm working from an air bnb and I don't know which ports the home's router blocks. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I just stopped my router wifi and switched on my phone hotspot, connect to laptop, then push again, yes it's solved!! thank you

Comment: I had this problem for a long time, I thought it was my router that is blocking the ports, until I dicifi investigate well and download that possibility. Thank you very much, now it works very well.

Comment: I did this and now get this error: kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host....any ideas?

Comment: For who didn't install nano (maybe for windows user), you could try `vim ~/.ssh/config` to edit the config.

Comment: If you put `RequestTTY no` and `User git` in your config, you don't have to type `-T` or `git@` in your `ssh` command.

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/troubleshooting-ssh/using-ssh-over-the-https-port

Comment: All of a sudden github stopped working for like half my repos, but worked for others.  This solutions works

Comment: I follow you and set Port `22`, it works fine.

Comment: This caused another problem: git@ssh.github.com: Permission denied (publickey).

Comment: My bad. The cause is that I did not add the ssh key to github after upgrading my ubuntu OS. After providing the ssh key to github, this approach worked for me.

Comment: Why the port 22 doesn't work? I thought it was because of GFW in China, but it seems that non-chinese programmers also come into this probem..

Comment: @gaoqiang Any firewall can cause this problem, not just the GFW. Some people are using a wireless device where the network owner blocks all port 22. I think this is to prevent infected devices from attacking SSH servers, but it could be for any raeson. Other people may have a restrictive home ISP or a work network configuration.

Comment: This works for me where the previous config is: `HostName github.com` only. Thanks!

Answer (score 76):

Create a `config` file in the `.ssh` folder:

```
Host github.com
User git
Hostname ssh.github.com
PreferredAuthentications publickey
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
Port 443

Host gitlab.com
Hostname altssh.gitlab.com
User git
Port 443
PreferredAuthentications publickey
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Comment: See Mahan_F answer for detailed explanation on why this happens.

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me on GitLab. Thanks, Isaque!

Comment: Thank you, I finally managed to set up github on a cPanel.

Comment: The details from Mahan_F are here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52817036/1603480

Answer (score 52):

**Basic URL Rewriting**
Git provides a way to rewrite URLs using the git config. Run:

```
git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://
```

Now, all git commands will perform a substitution of `git://` to `https://`

*source:*
[git:// protocol blocked by company, how can I get around that?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4891527/git-protocol-blocked-by-company-how-can-i-get-around-that/10729634#10729634)

Comment: Thanks! Ours was during the Jenkins build so I couldn't manually edit the git file (I don't have the git credentials for the jenkins account) - so this was very useful.

Comment: This is great. I've added git aliases for each to easily switch

Comment: Concerning github, the command should be: `git config --global url."https://github.com/".insteadOf git@github.com:`. Notice the differences: `@` becomes `//` and `:` becomes `/`.

Comment: Is this just replacing SSH with HTTPS ? This is no real solution.

Answer (score 23):

I faced the same problem and couldn't find a working solution. I faced this problem while setting up a local server and the git couldn't connect through my proxy network but my workstation could. This was the output when I ran the command 
 `ssh -vT git@github.com`

```
ubuntu@server:~$ ssh -vT git@github.com
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.8, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/ubuntu/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to github.com [13.234.176.102] port 22.
```

So I tried using an SSH connection made over the HTTPS port by editing the config file  `~/.ssh/config` but to no avail.

```
Host github.com
 Hostname ssh.github.com
 Port 443
```

Finally, I found this [article](https://pcarleton.com/2016/11/10/ssh-proxy/) which solved and exposed the real problem.

```
# github.com
Host github.com
    Hostname ssh.github.com
    ProxyCommand nc -X connect -x <PROXY-HOST>:<PORT> %h %p
    Port 443
    ServerAliveInterval 20
    User git
```

This is my config file and now git works perfectly well through ssh!

Comment: I particularly had to add `Hostname` and `Port` lines to my config, and viola, it works now.

Comment: @Animesh Singh what is <proxy-Host>:<port> here ??

Comment: @Animesh Singh  is it  **github.com:443**
am i right ?

Comment: If proxy requires authentication: https://adangel.org/2020/10/15/github-behind-proxy/

Answer (score 19):

**Quick workaround: try switching to a different network**

I experienced this problem while on a hotspot (3/4G connection). Switching to a different connection (WiFi) resolved it, but it's just a workaround - I didn't get the chance to get to the bottom of the issue so the other answers might be more interesting to determine the underlying issue

Comment: I switched from the WiFi to the 4G and it worked.  I don't understand either.

Answer (score 9):

For me, the problem was from my Internet Service Provider (ISP) -- port 22 (ssh) was not enabled. So I asked them to enable the port on the network and it started working.

To see if this is the issue, connect to your mobile hotspot and run:

`ssh -T git@bitbucket.org` or `git pull`
If it works, then ask your ISP to enable port 22.

Comment: This resolved the issue for me. Switched to a 4G hotspot and `git push` worked. But I turned off the hotspot, switched back to the old network...and now git works again. Who knows?

Answer (score 9):

Try

`ssh -T -p 443 git@ssh.github.com`

instead of

`ssh -T git@github.com`

Comment: what does it mean if even this fails?

Answer (score 7):

This answer is based on the comment to the main question from @zundi (to whom credit should go, thanks zundi):

- Create a hotspot on your mobile device and connect to the hotspot
- `git push`
- Turn off the hotspot on your mobile device and reconnect to the original network
- `git push` continues to work

I do not know why temporarily connecting to a hotspot magically "kickstarts" the original network connection.

Answer (score 4):

Execute:

```
nc -v -z <git-repository> <port>
```

Your output should look like:

```
"Connection to <git-repository> <port> port [tcp/*] succeeded!"
```

If you get:

```
connect to <git-repository> <port> (tcp) failed: Connection timed out
```

You need to edit your ~/.ssh/config file. Add something like the following:

```
Host example.com
Port 1234
```

Comment: I'm not sure everyone is going to have `nc` installed. What is that supposed to be? Netcat or something?

Answer (score 4):

In a similar failure mode as Ludder, I was getting this error when I hadn't yet signed-in to correct company VPN at my company.

Answer (score 3):

I was having this same issue, but the answer I found was different, thought someone might come across this issue, so here is my solution.

I had to whitelist 2 IPs for port `22`, `80`, `443`, and `9418`:

- `192.30.252.0/22`
- `185.199.108.0/22`

In case these IP's don't work, it might be because they got updated, you can find the most current ones on [this page](https://help.github.com/articles/github-s-ip-addresses/).

Comment: How did you add them into a whitelist?

Answer (score 3):

My computer was unable to connect port 22 while connecting to Github. I never had this issue with bitbucket. If you have both GitHub and bitbucket then

```
Host bitbucket.org
Hostname  altssh.bitbucket.org
Port  443


Host github.com
Hostname ssh.github.com
Port 443
```

[ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52057705/how-to-resolve-port-22-connection-timeout)

It basically connects SSH in 443 port instead of 22.

Answer (score 2):

The main reason was the change from the proxy installed by the company recently, which has blocked other ssh connections other than those to the company domain.

I was able to connect successfully by following these steps:

1. Double checked that the issue is what I am assuming by
   `ssh -T git@github.com`

It should end up in a timeout.

2. Edited the local remote URL by

`ssh config --local -e`

and from

`url=git@github.com:asheeshjanghu/Journal.git`

to

`url=https://github.com/asheeshjanghu/Journal.git`

The important point is that in the url you have to change at 2 places.

from `git@` to `https://`  and from `github:username` to `github/username`

In the end verify by doing a `git fetch`

Comment: I think `ssh config --local -e` should actually be `git config --local -e`, can you please check?

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue when working over a public library's wifi.

Running PowerShell `test-netconnection github.com -port 22` showed that they were blocking outbound connections on that port (lots of places seem to only allow HTTP ports; i.e. `80` and `443`).

Thankfully, GitHub allows you to access SSH over port 443 too: [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/troubleshooting-ssh/using-ssh-over-the-https-port)

Instead of running `git clone git@github.com:myOrg/myRepo.git`, make the following tweaks:

- Add `ssh://` to the start of the URL
- Connect to the `ssh` subdomain (i.e. `ssh.github.com` instead of just `github.com`)
- Add the port after the hostname: i.e. `:443`.
- Amend the colon before your org/username to a slash.

So for the above example you'd run: `git clone ssh://git@ssh.github.com:443/myOrg/myRepo.git`

This may give you a warning about the authenticity of the host; but (assuming you're happy*), answering `YES` to that will allow the command to run.  To decide if you should answer YES, check the fingerprint given in this warning against [GitHub's published fingerprints](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/githubs-ssh-key-fingerprints).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and it seems like something changed on my ISP. I will leave my solution here for future reference. At first I checked my gitconfig.

```
$ cat ~/.gitconfig
[user]
    name = ****
    email = ***@***.com
[url "git@github.com:"]
    insteadOf = https://github.com
```

As it explains my requests from git clients are forwarding to `git@github.com:`, I tried to ping with the server with ssh.

```
$ ssh -T git@github.com
ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Connection timed out
```

So, I appears that I can not connect to host github.com from my machine. So, I tried to connect the ssh port instead. This time connection was successful.

```
$ ssh -T -p 443 git@ssh.github.com
Hi raihankhan! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

So, I changed my `~/.gitconfig` like the following and git push/pull/clone requests were back to working state!

```
[user]
    name = *****
    email = ***@*****.com

[url "ssh://git@ssh.github.com:443/"]
    insteadOf = git@github.com:
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer above gave me the information needed to resolve this issue. In my case the url was incorrectly starting with ssh:///

To check the url in your git config is correct, open the git config file :-

```
git config --local -e
```

Check the url entry. It should NOT have ssh:/// at the start.

Incorrect entry:

```
 url = ssh:///git@github.com:username/repo.git
```

Correct entry:

```
 url = git@github.com:username/repo.git
```

If your url is correct, then the next step would be to try the answer above that suggests changing protocol to http.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the repo url from ssh to https is not very meaningful to me. As I prefer `ssh` over `https` because of some sort of extra benefits which I don't want to discard. Above answers are pretty good and accurate. If you face this problem in GitLab, please go to their official documentation [page](https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2016/02/18/gitlab-dot-com-now-supports-an-alternate-git-plus-ssh-port/) and change your config file like that.

```
Host gitlab.com
  Hostname altssh.gitlab.com
  User git
  Port 443
  PreferredAuthentications publickey
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/gitlab
```

Answer (score 1):

Restart the computer solved it for me.
Git version: `2.27.0.windows.1`
OS version: `Windows 10`

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was caused by a setting that I had changed on my Router a day before.
So on my Router, I just had to revert the setting **Isolation** to **disable**  and it has fixed my issue.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For my case, I didn't change anything in my PC. My workaround was:

- Restart the PC.
- Connect PC network with mobile hotspot or use Cloudflare WARP for private network.
- Do your work and chill :D

Answer (score 1):

If your `ssh -T git@github.com`  connects and does not time out but you're still getting the error when trying to `git commit`:

```
ssh: connect to host sign port 22: Operation timed out?

fatal: failed to write commit object:
```

Ive been able to fix the issue by disabling gpgsign in .gitconfig

```
[commit]
    gpgsign = false
```

Running MacOs, Not under proxy. Im guessing the complete solution is to generate and re assign new gpg keys but ive been at this for hours so perhaps tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue on a server of mine that was set up with it's regular IP and a failover IP. The failover IP did not point to the server at this time. I had to remove the failover IP from the server configuration in `/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml`. Pointing the failover IP to that server would have probably solved the issue as well.

Answer (score 0):

Refreshing my Internet connection worked for me.

Also if you use mobile hotspot - restart of mobile device was solution in my case.

Comment: git: 'reload' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

Answer (score -1):

When I accidentally switched to a *guest* wifi network I got this error. Had to switch back to my **default** wifi network.

Answer (score -1):

#### ISSUE

Step to produce issue: `git clone git@github.com:sramachand71/test.git`
for the first time in the new laptop

#### ERROR

```
ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Connection timed out
 fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

 Please make sure you have the correct access rights
 and the repository exists.
```

#### SOLUTION

for the first time in the system to clone we need to give double quotes for the clone command.

```
$ git clone "git@github.com:sramachand71/test.git"
```

I face this issue in the system even after everything was correct but noticed at last that double quote is must for url "repository_url.git" for first time or new user in the system.

Answer (score -1):

So I was having this same problem (not behind a proxy) and came across this question. Here's what I did to fix it:

Tried running `ssh -T git@github.com` and it did time out, but adding `-o KexAlgorithms=ecdh-sha2-nistp521` made a successful connection (found from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56348708/9555513) to a semi-related question).

To permanently fix this, I just added a line `KexAlgorithms=ecdh-sha2-nistp521` under `github.com` in my `~/.ssh/config`. Everything seems to work fine now.

Comment: That sets the Kex Algm to just the (comma-separated) arguments. If you want to _add_ some kex, you can prepend to the default list by starting your arguments with `^` like `^nist1,ed25519,etc`. `+` will append to and `-` will remove from the default list.

Answer (score -1):

If you are in windows, move into the directory where you stored your ssh key, and try again, it worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

What solved it for me was doing `ssh-add` on the key file.

```
ssh-add C:/Path/To/Key.pem
```

C:/Users/User/.ssh/config:

```
Host sshapp
    Hostname ssh.github.com
    IdentityFile C:/Path/To/Key.pem
    Port 443
```

Then clone using:

```
>git clone git@sshapp:<git_user>/app.git
Cloning into 'app'...
The authenticity of host '[ssh.github.com]:443 ([140.82.121.35]:443)' can't be established.
ED25519 key fingerprint is SHA256:+DiY3wvvV6T.....vCOqU.
```

Answer (score -1):

In my case,

1. I backup the `known_hosts` to `known_hosts.bk`
2. I clear all content of the old `known_hosts`.

Maybe it did remember the old host when I ssh using the other `.pem` file.

- **Error**

[image]

- **Success**

[image]

Answer (score -2):

I had this issue for 2 hours and it turns out removing the "s" from https and just do:

`git clone -b <branchName> http:<projecturl>`

Fixed it.

Comment: Please close this question tagging it as answered

Comment: What? This possibly cannot be the answer... The whole reason to have that "s" is to make a secure and encrypted link with the repo lol. Removing the "s" takes away the whole point of the question.

Comment: http is not secure

Answer (score -3):

Suggest to check the Internet connection or connect to another connection.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31393769)