# NPM failing on github branch dependency

Tags: node.js, github, npm, gulp, npm-install

I have the current dependency in my `package.json`:

```
"gulp": "github:gulpjs/gulp#4.0",
```

This has been working for some time but all of a sudden I get the following error:

```
λ npm i
npm WARN addRemoteGit Error: Command failed: git -c core.longpaths=true config --get remote.origin.url
npm WARN addRemoteGit
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:206:12)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:852:16)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:323:11)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at Pipe._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:492:12)
npm WARN addRemoteGit  gulpjs/gulp#4.0 resetting remote C:\Users\ekalkj\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-gulpjs-gulp-git-4-0-ecf98f08 because of error: { Error: Command failed: git -c core.longpaths=true config --get remote.origin.url
npm WARN addRemoteGit
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:206:12)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:852:16)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:323:11)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at Pipe._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:492:12)
npm WARN addRemoteGit   killed: false,
npm WARN addRemoteGit   code: 1,
npm WARN addRemoteGit   signal: null,
npm WARN addRemoteGit   cmd: 'git -c core.longpaths=true config --get remote.origin.url' }
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\ekalkj\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror git://github.com/gulpjs/gulp.git C:\Users\ekalkj\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-gulpjs-gulp-git-4-0-ecf98f08: Cloning into bare repository 'C:\Users\ekalkj\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-gulpjs-gulp-git-4-0-ecf98f08'...
npm WARN addRemoteGit gulpjs/gulp#4.0 pre-existing cached repo C:\Users\ekalkj\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-https-github-com-gulpjs-gulp-git-4-0-4b46db44 points to undefined and not https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp.git
npm ERR! git submodule -q update --init --recursive: Unable to determine absolute path of git directory
npm ERR! git submodule -q update --init --recursive:
npm WARN addRemoteGit Error: Command failed: git -c core.longpaths=true config --get remote.origin.url
npm WARN addRemoteGit
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:206:12)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:852:16)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:215:5)
npm WARN addRemoteGit  gulpjs/gulp#4.0 resetting remote C:\Users\ekalkj\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-gulpjs-gulp-git-4-0-7c06e801 because of error: { Error: Command failed: git -c core.longpaths=true config --get remote.origin.url
npm WARN addRemoteGit
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:206:12)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:852:16)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:215:5)
npm WARN addRemoteGit   killed: false,
npm WARN addRemoteGit   code: 1,
npm WARN addRemoteGit   signal: null,
npm WARN addRemoteGit   cmd: 'git -c core.longpaths=true config --get remote.origin.url' }
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\ekalkj\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror git@github.com:gulpjs/gulp.git C:\Users\ekalkj\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-gulpjs-gulp-git-4-0-7c06e801: Cloning into bare repository 'C:\Users\ekalkj\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-gulpjs-gulp-git-4-0-7c06e801'...
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\ekalkj\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror git@github.com:gulpjs/gulp.git C:\Users\ekalkj\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-gulpjs-gulp-git-4-0-7c06e801: ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Connection timed out
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\ekalkj\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "i"
npm ERR! node v6.4.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.7
npm ERR! code 128

npm ERR! Command failed: git -c core.longpaths=true clone --template=C:\Users\ekalkj\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror git@github.com:gulpjs/gulp.git C:\Users\ekalkj\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-gulpjs-gulp-git-4-0-7c06e801
npm ERR! Cloning into bare repository 'C:\Users\ekalkj\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-gulpjs-gulp-git-4-0-7c06e801'...
npm ERR! ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Connection timed out
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Projects\danskespil.website\npm-debug.log
```

When I remove the gulp 4 dependency it's working like it should.

The same thing happens when doing `npm install glob-fs`, not that strange as it also uses a [branch or tag](https://github.com/jonschlinkert/glob-fs/blob/master/package.json#L42).

I think it might be the enterprise proxy, and npm that does something else when it's hitting a branch or tag.

I tried `git config --global url."https://github.com/".insteadOf git@github.com:` but with no luck, just a new error:

```
npm ERR! git submodule -q update --init --recursive: Unable to determine absolute path of git directory
npm ERR! git submodule -q update --init --recursive:
npm ERR! git submodule -q update --init --recursive: Unable to determine absolute path of git directory
npm ERR! git submodule -q update --init --recursive:
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\ekalkj\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "glob-fs"
npm ERR! node v6.4.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.7
npm ERR! code 1

npm ERR! Command failed: git -c core.longpaths=true submodule -q update --init --recursive
npm ERR! Unable to determine absolute path of git directory
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Projects\danskespil.website\npm-debug.log
```

I tried updating git-for-windows, nodejs and npm with no luck. I tried adding a proxy to the NPM configuration with no luck. I'm a bit lost, so what the next debugging step for this issue?

Comment: it says "ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Connection timed out"

Comment: `npm cache clean` then retry

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Connection timed out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15589682/ssh-connect-to-host-github-com-port-22-connection-timed-out)

Comment: Tried that, no luck. Also tried deleting the folder manually.

Answer (score 2):

```
github:gulpjs/gulp#4.0
```

Means that you want the 4.0 tag in the repository https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/tags

There is no tag 4.0

Maybe there was one and it was removed, I don't know, but as of today, this can't work.

Gulp is on npm https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp
So there is no need do write it that way.

You should have :

```
"gulp":"3.9.1"
```

[EDIT]

Yups, my bad, there is a BRANCH 4.0

So maybe try this :

```
"gulp":"git+ssh://git@github.com:gulpjs/gulp#4.0"
```

or

```
"gulp":"https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp.git#4.0"
```

Anyway, do you really need an unreleased branch of gulp ?

Comment: Both of the suggestions does not work. I tried them before, and tried them again. Yes unfortunately I need gulp 4 for the new API, and I can't really wait till they finally release it.

Comment: does github:gulpjs/gulp works ? I'm trying to see if the problem is just the branch or if it's more global.

Comment: That does not work, I'm thinking it's trying to get it via another protocol that might be blocked, but it's not transparent at all. And it worked before, but maybe something has changed.

Comment: Can you try to clone this repository ?

Comment: I mean git clone git...gulp

Comment: Works fine, with no problems at all.

Comment: That is a mystery... I'm out of idea. An ugly temporary solution would be to put gulp locally until the 4.0 release, but it doesn't resolve the problem. Good luck ! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14381898/local-dependency-in-package-json