# ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: on only a single project

Tags: ssh

I have been working on a particular repository for months with no problem,after a period of time i tried to make new push to remote repo and i got this

```
errorssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Connection timed out
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I TRIED THIS
i created a ssh key and added to my github but i still get this error, other projects on my github are working fine only this particular project has refused to accept git push

When i try ssh -Tv github.com i get this

```
untu-4ubuntu2.6, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to github.com [140.82.118.4] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 140.82.118.4 port 22: Connection timed out
debug1: Connecting to github.com [140.82.118.3] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 140.82.118.3 port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Connection timed out
```

Comment: What happens when you run `ssh -Tv github.com`?

Comment: it shows this OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.6, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to github.com [140.82.118.3] port 22.

Comment: @evolutionxbox here is what i get

Comment: untu-4ubuntu2.6, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to github.com [140.82.118.4] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 140.82.118.4 port 22: Connection timed out
debug1: Connecting to github.com [140.82.118.3] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 140.82.118.3 port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Connection timed out

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Connection timed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15589682/ssh-connect-to-host-github-com-port-22-connection-timed-out)