# Github ssh -T git@github.com and git functions are not working, hanging

Tags: github, ssh, ssh-keys

I am using manjaro linux. I've managed to setup ssh key before, but after i reinstall the OS, i failed after i've done all things with github ssh documents. my github commands are just waiting forever and generates this error: `ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Connection timed out`, Example;

```js
[maviay@manjaro ~]$ ssh -T git@github.com
ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Connection timed out
```

Comment: I've done [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52817036/17297758) and it works. Sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While a firewall issue could be a common cause for port 22 blocked, check this thread for a [wifi chipset driver](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/630624/7490) issue.

Said issue would not affect HTTPS (443), which is why your [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52817036/6309) is working:

```sh
# ~/.ssh/config
Host github.com
 Hostname ssh.github.com
 Port 443
```