# ssh: connect to host github.com port 22 and also 443: Connection timed out

Tags: github, ssh, timeout

I have a problem connecting to github using ssh.

I'm trying to use

```
ssh -T git@github.com
ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Connection timed out
```

or

```
ssh -T -p 443 git@ssh.github.com
ssh: connect to host ssh.github.com port 443: Connection timed out
```

so editing ~/.ssh/config (like suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15589682/ssh-connect-to-host-github-com-port-22-connection-timed-out)) does nothing for me

What I don't understand is that I can telnet the ssh port no problem whatsoever

```
telnet github.com 22
Trying 140.82.121.4...
Connected to github.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
SSH-2.0-babeld-e1420b26
```

Also when I use VPN or my phone as LTE hotspot everything works just fine. I have a mikrotik router which has not been touched or changed in a long time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I have finally found out the problem, it was because of invalid routing my ISP had.

Answer (score 0):

The next command is to add access data to our proxy to the file:

```
$ git config --global http.proxy http://proxyuser:proxypass@proxyaddress:8080
```