# git clone fails with ssh port 22 connection timed out

Tags: git, ssh

I stood up *CentOS 7* nix OS via *Oracle VM VirtualBox* from *Windows 11* workstation.  Then I installed latest *gitlab* via *Docker*. So far I was able to do followings:

- *gitlab* is running successfully
- I was able to access its web console from a browser
- I was able to create new user (non-root) as *John*
- I was able to create a new project as *hello-world* and create ssh key pairs for that user
- I have *git bash* running on *Windows 11* and ran **ssh-keygen** to create key pairs

The problem I am having is when I tried to run `git clone git@localhost:john/hello-world.git` I am getting **ssh: connect to host localhost.com port 22: Connection timed out
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.**.

I read a few articles about it including this and tried its suggested solution although I didn't understand it: [ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Connection timed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15589682/ssh-connect-to-host-github-com-port-22-connection-timed-out)

I'd appreciate if someone could explain to me why this is happening/how to resolve it. I am newbie in linux + networking + ssh.

**Update**:

This is not a solution to the question I posted but workaround temp solution for me.

Instead of using *ssh key*, I decided to use *username/password* which allowed me to download the repo in *git bash*. I did two things.

1. I added VM's IP address and its hostbame on *C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts* - This I should have done first, newbie's mistake.
2. Afterward, I ran `git clone http://john@localhost/john/hello-world.git`

Comment: Make sure your server is running an ssh server (`sshd`). Make sure your network configuration allows ssh traffic. This is a server setup issue, suitable for superuser.com or (more likely) serverfault.

Comment: This is more an ssh issue than a Git issue. Make sure you can ssh to your VM first.

Answer (score 1):

First make sure you can access your VM through ssh at all : run

```
ssh <user>@<host>

# you can add '-v' to have more information on what ssh is trying to do
```

---

Two remarks :

- host: if your VM is accessible through your hosts network, it won't be with the 127.0.0.1 IP (`localhost`). Try to connect to the VM's IP, or, if you added a name for your VM in your `etc/hosts`, to this name : `ssh git@mylocalvm`
- user account: you mention you created a `john` account, but not a `git` account. Either create a non root `git` account on your VM, or try `ssh john@mylocalvm`