# connecting github.com timed out

Tags: ubuntu, github, odoo, request-timed-out

I'm behind a router and trying to clone ODOO on Ubuntu using the code
`$ git clone https://github.com/odoo/odoo.git`

But it is not working showing time out for port 443

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15589682/ssh-connect-to-host-github-com-port-22-connection-timed-out/52817036#52817036)
The solution is to add these lines

```
Host github.com
 Hostname ssh.github.com
 Port 443
```

to this file /.ssh/config

But in my case, this directory > .ssh and file > config does not exist and if I used
`sudo nano ~/.ssh/config`
The system refuses to save the file even while I'm using the root user, it says:
Error writing /root/.ssh/config: No such file or directory

Also
It seems the same problem while I'm trying to install
 `sudo npm install -g rtlcss`

The result is: npm ERR! network timeout at: https://registry.npmjs.org/rtlcss

Any help please?
Everything was fine in the exact situation while I was directly connected to the internet, but now I'm under a router and using Hyper-V to run this Ubuntu.

Comment: Have you looked into finding out if you can reach github.com? Try network debugging tools like `nslookup` and `telnet` to narrow down where it's failing.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the problem was network problem. When I changed the Gateway it worked fine while I configured the router to allow 443