# Git clone gives "ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Connection timed out" Linux /opt directory Amazon EC2 Instance

Tags: linux, git, amazon-ec2, ssh

**Issue**
I am trying to use git in /opt/jamf2snipe directory on an EC2 Instance. I have tried the following command:
`sudo git clone git@github.com:MYUSERNAME/jamf2snipe-school.git`

It says connection timed out:

```
Cloning into 'jamf2snipe-school'...
ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Connection timed out
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

If I try to run this in my home directory it works fine. It seems to be a permission issue with /opt. I am wary of changing permissions for /opt.

**Setup**

I am trying to do this on an Amazon EC2 Instance. Currently SSH is limited to certain IP addresses (**not** including Github). I followed this article from [github](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/troubleshooting-ssh/using-ssh-over-the-https-port) to use SSH over HTTPS. I tested to make sure I had stuff setup correctly by using:

```
$ ssh -T git@github.com
```

received

```
Hi USERNAME! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

I did this in /opt/jamf2snipe and the home directory successfully.

Comment: `sudo git clone` vs `ssh -T git@github.com` — either use `sudo` both time or don't use `sudo` at all.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure to, if possible, *not* use `sudo`.
In addition of executing commands as `root` (which is dangerous), it uses its own environment variable, and SSH settings (in `/root/.ssh`), which differs from your normal EC2 user.

Conversely, making a repository in `/opt`, which might be accessible only by root, is not the best spot to clone a repository.

Second, [Using SSH over the HTTPS port](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/troubleshooting-ssh/using-ssh-over-the-https-port) is the usual solution ([like this one from 2018](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52817036/6309)) on EC2, where the firewall can block by default SSH egress traffic.