# git clone: connection to port 443 invalid format

Tags: git, github, ssh, bitbucket

I tried to clone a repo from bitbucket but it told me that the connection to bitbucket over port 22 timed out. I read a few solutions that said that I should use port 443 instead i.e. setting up a config file ([ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Connection timed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15589682/ssh-connect-to-host-github-com-port-22-connection-timed-out)) or specifying it over the git clone command (git clone ssh://git@altssh.bitbucket.org:443/workspace/repo.git). In both instances, when attempting to clone, I get an error like this:

```
Cloning into 'homerunner'...
kex_exchange_identification: banner line contains invalid characters 
banner exchange: Connection to (port_number) port 443: invalid format
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Are there any other solutions?

**EDIT**

I made a config file and ran the command `GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -v' git clone ssh://git@altssh.bitbucket.org:443/workspace/repo`

I got this error:

```
Cloning into 'homerunner'...
OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022
debug1: Reading configuration data ~/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to altssh.bitbucket.org [18.205.93.15] port 443.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file ~/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file ~/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file ~/.ssh/id_ed25519 type 3
debug1: identity file ~/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file ~/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file ~/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file ~/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file ~/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: identity file ~/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file ~/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.3
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 0: <HEAD><TITLE>Invalid HTTP Request</TITLE></HEAD>
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 1: <BODY BGCOLOR="white" FGCOLOR="black"><H1>Invalid HTTP Request</H1><HR>
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 2: <FONT FACE="Helvetica,Arial"><B>
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 3: Description: Bad request syntax</B></FONT>
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 4: <HR>
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 5: <!-- default "Invalid HTTP Request" response (400) -->
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 6: </BODY>
kex_exchange_identification: banner line contains invalid characters
banner exchange: Connection to 18.205.93.15 port 443: invalid format
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Comment: Port 443 is for `https://` addresses, not `ssh://`

Comment: Thanks for replying @Phil, unfortunately I got this error:


```
Cloning into 'homerunner'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://altssh.bitbucket.org:443/sacgf/homerunner.git/': gnutls_handshake() failed: An unexpected TLS packet was received.
```

Comment: @Phil normally, yes, but Bitbucket runs an SSH daemon on `altssh.bitbucket.org:443`. GitHub and GitLab do something similar as well.

@Yasir - what do you get for `GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -v' git clone ssh://git@altssh.bitbucket.org:443/workspace/repo`?

Comment: @JimRedmond ah, I missed the `altssh` part. Good to know

Comment: Also: you don't have to obscure the IP address for publicly available services like Bitbucket.

Comment: I still get the same error (full message is too long):


kex_exchange_identification: banner line contains invalid characters
banner exchange: Connection to (port) port 443: invalid format
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Comment: I asked for the full message because what you provided isn't enough detail. Could you please update the original question with the full message?

Comment: Thank you. Do you use an HTTPS proxy?

Comment: I don't think I do