# Git Server Denying Access

Tags: git, ssh, ubuntu-14.04

I have a VPS that is setup with GIT. I can access the server using the user name of git through ssh.

```
$ssh gitvps   <-- Local 
git@linux-vps:~$ <-- Now remote
```

My config file on the local machine looks like -

```
Host gitvps
     HostName SERVERIP
     User git
     Port 22
     IdentityFile "~/.ssh/server/git/id_rsa"
```

I ran the command ssh -vT gitvps and it says Authenticated but after it reached debus1:Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8 it hangs.

When I try to push to my remote using git, it says my key is denied. However, all signs point to me being able to connect just fine

```
git git@gitvps:/home/git/test.git
```

Permission Denied. Is it not possible to use an SSH config file to break up all of my id_rsa keys when using GIT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it not possible to use an SSH config file to break up all of my id_rsa keys when using GIT?

It is possible, and the url of the git repo will be `gitvps:/home/git/test.git` (no need for the prefix `git@`)

For the IdentityFile part of the `.ssh/config` file, I prefer using the full path rather than relying on `~`.

Make sure your `.bashrc`, or `.profile` or `.bash_profile` in your remote server does not do any echo, and does not trigger any process that would not return immediately.

Check also your router, firewall or anti-virus, as mentioned in "[git clone hangs forever on github](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8773193/6309)".

---

As the [OP Aaron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1583066/aaron) mentions in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32683674/6309), adding `ForwardAgent yes` helps.
See "[GitHub: Using SSH agent forwarding](https://developer.github.com/guides/using-ssh-agent-forwarding/)" and [this article](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/ssh-agent-forwarding.html):

> agent forwarding. In short, this allows a chain of ssh connections to forward key challenges back to the original agent, obviating the need for passwords or private keys on any intermediate machines

So that would be useful if there is an intermediate (proxy?) server between the user and the git repo hosting server.
Although, in case of proxy, the article "[SSH Agent Forwarding considered harmful](https://heipei.github.io/2015/02/26/SSH-Agent-Forwarding-considered-harmful/)" would recommend using a `ProxyCommand` directive instead.

Comment: I have fixed my issue. I added an answer but my new problem is I don't understand how it fixed it. I added ForwardAgent to my config and now things work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I added ForwardAgent yes to my ssh config file and now it works. I don't understand why but I was desperate and tried a fix for a problem someone else was having. I can now clone and push.

It would be nice if someone could explain why ForwardAgent would be of use in solving my issue.

Comment: Interesting. https://heipei.github.io/2015/02/26/SSH-Agent-Forwarding-considered-harmful/ is a good read.

Comment: I have edited my answer to add some clues regarding ForwardAgent.