# Git hanging with npm dependency

Tags: git

I have git v1.7.1 and a npm package dependency defined like:

```
git+http://samePlace.com/npmPackage.git#master
```

And when I execute `npm install --proxy="..."`

```
npm info git [ 'clone',
npm info git   '--template=/home/talabes/.npm/_git-remotes/_templates',
npm info git   '--mirror',
npm info git   'http://samePlace.com/npmPackage.git',
npm info git   '/home/talabes/.npm/_git-remotes/git-http-npmPackage-c449d2f24b90c6ad068a33db48c38760' ]
```

git just hangs... I tried to clone without npm and it also hangs. So the problem is not NPM. I tried with `git 2.3.0` and it worked.

Any idea of how I can work-around this git issue? 
Is it some bug fixed in some version? Because `--mirror` and `--template` exist in v1.7.1.

**I need to define the dependency as `git+http` and I can't update git**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git clone hangs forever on github](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8750930/git-clone-hangs-forever-on-github)

Comment: None of those solutions solved my problem. No `git` nor `https` work. Disabling the proxy is not an option either...

Comment: The duplicate also has lots of tips how to produce debug logs. Here's another one: http://askubuntu.com/questions/336907/really-verbose-way-to-test-git-connection-over-ssh - follow those steps and post the logs here if the problem persists.