# git clone hangs on "Cloning into..." using GitBash

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to clone a repository from my organization's GitHub using GitBash, but when I do a `git clone`, it hangs indefinitely. The output is as follows:

```
git clone https://github.com/myorganization/myrepository
Cloning into 'myrepository'...
```

I have looked at other stackoverflow pages. [git clone hangs forever on github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8750930/git-clone-hangs-forever-on-github) suggests trying to cone using `git clone git@github.com/myorganization/myrepository`, which didn't work. It also suggests doing `GIT_TRACE=1 GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 git clone --verbose https://github.com/myorganization/myrepository`. When I do that, I notice that it's hanging at:

```
[...]
11:44:04.432276 http.c:721              <= Recv header, 0000000057 bytes (0x00000039)
11:44:04.432276 http.c:733              <= Recv header: x-github-request-id: CEEF:07BD:11FD966:1D089D5:60D380F4
11:44:04.432276 http.c:721              <= Recv header, 0000000023 bytes (0x00000017)
11:44:04.432276 http.c:733              <= Recv header: x-frame-options: DENY
11:44:04.432276 http.c:721              <= Recv header, 0000000002 bytes (0x00000002)
11:44:04.432276 http.c:733              <= Recv header:
11:44:04.432276 http.c:774              == Info: Connection #0 to host github.com left intact
```

(I can show the whole output if necessary.)

I've also looked at [Git clone, push and pull all hang with no messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54192528/git-clone-push-and-pull-all-hang-with-no-messages), which suggests that it may be a network issue. To diagnose the network issue, I installed GitHub Desktop, and tried the clone, which works fine. Therefore, it's not a network issue.

I've tried some other things too:

- I confirmed that I have access to my GitHub repository (I'm listed as a member in the repo)
- I've reset my username and email using `git config --global user.name[email]` to something random to trigger a login for the repo. (A login never came.)
- I've re-installed GitBash following [this](https://www.stanleyulili.com/git/how-to-install-git-bash-on-windows/) guide.
- I've also tried (un)setting http/https proxies with `git config --global --unset http.proxy` and `git config --global --unset https.proxy`

If someone could help me solve this problem, I'd appreciate it. Thank-you.

Comment: How large is the repo you're trying to clone?

Comment: Very small. It's one text file with two lines in it.

Comment: what is the version of git-for-windows?

Comment: 2.32.0.windows.1

Answer (score 12, accepted):

this helped me: https://github.com/microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-Core/issues/364
Basically, I just had to put this command `git config --global credential.provider generic` and then clone.

Hope it works for you as well.

Comment: Great! the command `git config --global credential.provider generic`  definitely works! After running it in GitBash appeared the window of credential helper to put user and password which didn't open automatically before. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

If you have enabled ssh for your account then it is due to same reason.  I also faced it and with below command you can easily avoid hang problem during clone.

- ssh -T git@github.com (This command will authenticate you over ssh)
- git clone git@github.com:[user]/[repo]

Answer (score 0):

The issue for me when I ran into this was that it was a private repo and I accidentally used the HTTPS URL instead of the SSH url, and so it was hanging on the missing the credentials. Since I already has SSH keys setup locally and in GitHub, I just switched over to the SSH url.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem because port 22 was blocked by my firewall. Make sure to open that port. For example with `ufw`:

```bash
ufw allow out ssh
```