# Clone the repository to use Python with Azure functions

Tags: python, git, azure, github, cmd

Trying to figure out the issue with my cmd as it is getting stucked.

As I tried to run below commands to get the virtual env enabled..

```
cd start
python -m venv .venv
source .venv/bin/activate
```

This is working but when I try to clone the repo my cmd is getting stucked, below are those commands, also those repo is also a sample one.

```
git clone https://github.com/Azure-Samples/functions-python-pytorch-tutorial.git
cd functions-python-pytorch-tutorial
```

Here my task is to use PyTorch. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: The `cmd` tag is for Microsoft Windows `cmd.exe` issues. Are you on Windows? Are you running `git-bash`? From where does the `source` command come?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you [Luis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16424415/luis) and [shaILU](https://stackoverflow.com/users/783890/shailu). Posting your suggestion as an answer to help other community members.

If you are using `git-bash`, you can try running following command:

```
git config --global credential.provider generic
```

If you have enabled `ssh`, then try following commands:

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

```
git clone git@github.com:[user]/[repo]
```

You can refer to [git clone hangs on "Cloning into..." using GitBash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68119535/git-clone-hangs-on-cloning-into-using-gitbash), [Pushing with Windows built-in OpenSSH hangs](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/3779) and [Clone new Repository 'hangs' indefinitely](https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/issues/1189)